# How to add new row from last using swimlane/ngx-datatable

Tags: angular7, angular8, angular10, ngx-datatable, angular11

Tried to add new row to swimlane/ngx-datatable but not working properly. I want to add new row to from last but in my code it is adding on that same row.If you see my stackblitz demo you can understand my issue.Click on addnewrow option and see it.I do not know how to combine rowData and data to add the new row in the table. How to resolve this issue.

Note: We can use the addNewRow option(button or link) outside of table.

app.component.html:

```
  <ng-template #buttonsTemplate let-row="row" let-value="value" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
     <div class="actions"> 
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)='addNewRow(row,rowIndex)'> AddNewRow </a>  
     </div>
  </ng-template>
```

app.component.ts:

```
 addNewRow(data, rowIndex) {
    //Copy the data
    let rowData = {
      name: "Beryl Rice New",
      gender: "Male",
      company: "Velity",
      actions: ""
    };

    //rowData.BATCH_CODE = "";
    //rowData.qty = 0;
    this.rows.splice(rowIndex, 0, rowData);
    this.rows = [...this.rows];
  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymttep?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Please update your addNewRow() method

```
this.rows.splice(rows.length, 0, rowData);
```